# terminal shuts down immediately after 17.10 upgrade

Tags: command-line, upgrade, zsh

Well this one has me stumped: I can't log in to any terminal.  Every time I try to open a terminal or log on, I am logged out instantly, even when I do this from `ctrl-alt-f1`.  Now, before the upgrade I was using `zsh`, so I expect that something is screwed up with `zsh`.  Normally, I'd just change the shell to bash, or go in and mess around with my `.zshrc` until something works but: I can't do anything.  Absolutely nothing.  Any ideas?

Comment: Use Alt-F2 to run `gnome-terminal -x bash`. Does bash work?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with tmux getting screwed up.  I'm still not sure what happened to it, but I shouldn't be surprised as I was not using the one from the package manager.  I used a GUI text editor to disable the line in my `.zshrc` that started tmux.  (Even this was tricky because the GUI file browser hides dot files. Fortunately the GNOME GUI text editor let me type in the file name.)  The terminal now works fine but with no tmux (which I am sure I will now be able to fix).